# (Differential Geometry) Sectional ball curvature S²

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to know how to calculate the sectional curvature of the sphere S², using the formula. My question is in the school of tangent vectors TpM. Could someone help me, for example explain the steps to calculate.

Comment: Using which formula?

Comment: The sectional curvature formula, where it involves the riemann tensor. Essa aqui K(sigma)=K(X,Y)= <R(X,Y)Y,X>/|X|²|Y|²<X,Y>. The metric of the S² sphere is that 2x2 matrix, where the elements of the main diagonal are a² and a²sin² (theta) and the remaining elements are null.

Comment: My suggestion is to edit your question using MathJax (see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference): In an edit, explain which formula you want to use and explain what your thoughts are about the question, for instance, can you compute the Riemannian connection on the sphere?